Jimu Redux Extension - myStore is undefined
I am following the example for building a Jimu Redux extension here. After implementing this demo, the myStore part of state is undefined. What am I in missing this example?
Extension
import { type extensionSpec, type ImmutableObject, type IMState } from 'jimu-core'

export enum MyActionKeys {
  MyAction1 = 'MY_ACTION_1',
  MyAction2 = 'MY_ACTION_2',
}

export interface Action1 {
  type: MyActionKeys.MyAction1
  val: string
}

export interface Action2 {
  type: MyActionKeys.MyAction2
  val: string
}

type ActionTypes = Action1 | Action2

interface MyState {
  a: string
  b: string
}
type IMMyState = ImmutableObject<MyState>

declare module 'jimu-core/lib/types/state'{
  interface State {
    myState?: IMMyState
  }
}

export default class MyReduxStoreExtension implements extensionSpec.ReduxStoreExtension {
  id = 'my-local-redux-store-extension'

  getActions () {
    return Object.keys(MyActionKeys).map(k => MyActionKeys[k])
  }

  getInitLocalState () {
    return {
      a: '123',
      b: null
    }
  }

  getReducer () {
    return (localState: IMMyState, action: ActionTypes, appState: IMState): IMMyState => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case MyActionKeys.MyAction1:
          return localState.set('a', action.val)
        case MyActionKeys.MyAction2:
          return localState.set('b', action.val)
        default:
          return localState
      }
    }
  }

  getStoreKey () {
    return 'myState'
  }
}

Mainfest
{
    "name": "my-store",
    "label": "Redux",
    "type": "widget",
    "version": "1.14.0",
    "exbVersion": "1.14.0",
    "author": "test",
    "description": "This is the redux store.",
    "copyright": "",
    "license": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0",
    "properties": {},
    "extensions": [
      {
        "name": "My store",
        "point": "REDUX_STORE",
        "uri": "extensions/my-store"
      }
    ],
    "translatedLocales": [
      "en"
    ],
    "defaultSize": {
      "width": 800,
      "height": 500
    }
  }

Unit Test Result


Please add the error message as text in the body of the Question. Images are not legible on all devices (especially black background), and can't be searched by others.

I have found a solution to my problem. This seems to contradict the demo project provided by ESRI but it works. In this situation, state was available when page loaded but state was modified later by extensions. I'm sure there are better approaches if you know of any please provide them.
import { React, type AllWidgetProps, jsx, type IMState } from 'jimu-core'
import { Input } from 'jimu-ui'

export default class Widget extends React.PureComponent<AllWidgetProps<unknown> & { state: IMState }, unknown> {
  /**
   * Map the state your widget needs
   * @param state
   */
  static mapExtraStateProps (state: IMState) {
    return { state: state } // From demo: { a: state.myState.a }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="widget-use-redux jimu-widget m-2">
        <div data-testid="a">{this.props.state.myState.a}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

